# Determine the diameter of the graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We have the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and we want to determine the diameter of the graph.

For that do we have to calculate the eigenvalues? Or isn't the diameter related to the number of eigenvalues?

Comment: There are so few ones! You may be better off drawing  a diagram, in this case at  least.

Comment: Every node is connected with the next and the previous one, except the first one that is only connected to the next one and teh last node is only connected to the previous one. Isn't the graph like that? But which is then te graph? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: I edited the matrix. So since each node is connected to the next and previous one, is the diameter equal to $1$ ? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: No, the diameter is the maximum distance between any two points. In this case, the diameter is $4$. The number of distinct eigenvalues is $5$, however, as the answer below points out. Also, the number of distinct eigenvalues definitely exceeds the diameter, so the number of distinct eigenvalues forms a lower bound of the diameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117501/g-graph-of-diameter-d-implies-an-adjacency-matrix-with-at-least-d1-distinct-eig) answer, in your case the matrix $A$ has 5 distinct  eigenvalues $\{0,\pm 2, \pm 2^{1/2}\}$, whereas the [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) is 4

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The matrix $A$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) with $n=8$

$$
C={\begin{pmatrix}c_{0}&c_{{n-1}}&\dots &c_{{2}}&c_{{1}}\\c_{{1}}&c_{0}&c_{{n-1}}&&c_{{2}}\\\vdots &c_{{1}}&c_{0}&\ddots &\vdots \\c_{{n-2}}&&\ddots &\ddots &c_{{n-1}}\\c_{{n-1}}&c_{{n-2}}&\dots &c_{{1}}&c_{0}\\\end{pmatrix}}.
$$

it is a well known result that the eigenvalues of this type of matrix  are given by

$$
{\displaystyle \lambda _{j}=c_{0}+c_{n-1}\omega _{j}+c_{n-2}\omega _{j}^{2}+\ldots +c_{1}\omega _{j}^{n-1},\qquad j=0,1,\ldots ,n-1} 
$$

where $\omega_j = e^{2\pi i j /n}$ are the $n$-th roots of unity

Comment: Did you find the eigenvalues using some trick, or using a computer program? I am asking because I struggled to get the pattern by hand. If you have got it by hand, then explaining that would be a nice edit.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks for the suggestion, I just included an edit

Comment: That is a very nice result, I will look it up. +1.